# How to count occurrences of a specific dict key in dicts list and some dicts values ​contains list and append the count in value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the number of times a specified key occurs in my `list` of `dict`s. I've used loops and sum to count up all the keys, but how can I find the count for a specific key? I have this code, which does not work currently:

```
for dico in data:
    for ele in dico['people']:
                  print(ele['name']+str(len(ele['animals'])))
```

The "entries" data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Uzuzozne",
    "people": [
      {
        "name": "Lillie Abbott",
        "animals": [
          {
            "name": "John Dory"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Satanwi",
    "people": [
      {
        "name": "Anthony Bruno",
        "animals": [
          {
            "name": "Oryx"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Dillauti",
    "people": [
      {
        "name": "Winifred Graham",
        "animals": [
          { "name": "Anoa" },
          { "name": "Duck" },
          { "name": "Narwhal" },
          { "name": "Badger" },
          { "name": "Cobra" },
          { "name": "Crow" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Blanche Viciani",
        "animals":
          [{ "name": "Barbet" },
          { "name": "Rhea" },
          { "name": "Snakes" },
          { "name": "Antelope" },
          { "name": "Echidna" },
          { "name": "Crow" },
          { "name": "Guinea Fowl" },
          { "name": "Deer Mouse" }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My goal is to print the counts of People and Animals by counting the number of children and appeng it in the name, eg. `Satanwi [2]`.

```
[ { name: 'Dillauti [5]',
    people:
     [ { name: 'Winifred Graham [6]',
         animals:
          [ { name: 'Anoa' },
            { name: 'Duck' },
            { name: 'Narwhal' },
            { name: 'Badger' },
            { name: 'Cobra' },
            { name: 'Crow' } ] },
       { name: 'Blanche Viciani [8]',
         animals:
          [ { name: 'Barbet' },
            { name: 'Rhea' },
            { name: 'Snakes' },
            { name: 'Antelope' },
            { name: 'Echidna' },
            { name: 'Crow' },
            { name: 'Guinea Fowl' },
            { name: 'Deer Mouse' } ] },
      ...
...
]
```

Comment: In your output example, whence does [5] come from for Dillauti ??

Comment: sorry for the error it's 8+6+2= [16]

Comment: Ok so it's the total of "people" + their animals ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want; feel free to ask if you need explanations:

```
for dico in data:
    children = 0
    for ele in dico['people']:
        animals = len(ele['animals'])
        children += 1 + animals
        ele['name'] += f" [{animals}]"
    dico['name'] += f" [{children}]"
```

Comment: can we optimise more the code ?

Comment: I think this is pretty optimal given the structure of your embedded dicts and lists. In which way would you want to optimize it ?

Comment: avoiding nested loops, maybe ?

Comment: My nested loops don't iterate over the same objects, they just fit the nested structure of your dictionary; so there's no efficiency loss (unlike for example nested looping over the same iterable, that yields an O(n^2) complexity).